# mysql How do I calculate the odds of winning a match as a percentage?

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, phpmyadmin, mysql-connector

I have two tables, one for the finalized matches and the other for the current bulletin.

i want to do

If there is a matching league in the current bulletin and the result of this match is 1, how many matches have been given in the resulting table and how many won, I want to get it as %

Current matches table

table = current

```
Id        team                mr1      league
--------------------------------------------------
22    Galatasaray-Altay        2.10      TUR
23    Asteras Tripolis-Pana    1.30      GRECE
24    Dortmud-Leipzing         1.15      GER
25    Valencia-Celta Vigo      1.10      SPAN
```

finished matches table

table = concluded

```
 Id        team              sccore        mr1      league
-----------------------------------------------------------
1    Barceolana-Realmadrid    2-1          1.10      SPAN
2    Cavalier-Waterhouse FC   1-3          2.10      JAM
3    B.Munih-Shalke04         4-0          1.15      GER
4    A.Madrid-Sevilla         0-0          1.10      SPAN
5    Real Betis-Getafe        2-3          1.75      SPAN
6    Granada-Levante          1-0          1.10      SPAN
7    U.Berlin-Mainz           2-3          1.15      GER
```

When you look at it, the mr1s of the two leagues match
current table
SPAN mr1 1.10
GER  MR1 1.15

SPAN 1.10 results given to a total of 3 matches
2-1
0-0
1-0
GER 1.15 results given to a total of 2 matches
2-3
4-0

I need to find how many matches won, how many matches lost, and find the probability of winning by breaking down the results of this match.

SPAN total 3 match 1.10 2win 1 draw

100/$totalmac*$win; = probability of winning %66.666666666667

GER total 2 match 1.15 win 1 draw

100/$totalmac*$win; = probability of winning %50

what i want to do briefly

```
Id        team                mr1      league   percent
-------------------------------------------------------
24    Dortmud-Leipzing         1.15      GER    %50
25    Valencia-Celta Vigo      1.10      SPAN   %66.66
```